# Is there a way to automatically initialize classes that I've created setting default values for each of the properties?

Tags: c#, object, model

This is for writing test cases, say I have a class TestClass and that class has properties string name, int age, image tstimage etc. Does something exist that can automatically initialize an instance of TestClass while setting default values of all the properties so for example the name will be a default string value of "default" or something, same with int and image?

Comment: Why not set the default in the class itself, or in its constructor? (Note that it's better to *show* a sample of the code than *describe* it...)

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Set the values in the default constructor
2. Set the attributes where they are declared in the class

It all depends on the exact goal you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Could do it in your constructor

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        public string s1 {get;set;}
        public string s2 {get;set;}

        public TestClass()
        {
            s1 = "foo";
            s2 = "bar";
        }
    }
```

Maybe using an object initializer?

```
    public class TestClass
    {
        public string s1 {get;set;}
        public string s2 {get;set;}
    }

    var testClass = new TestClass{
        s1 = "foo",
        s2 = "bar"
    };
```